# C# ADO.NET Exception: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection

Hi I am trying to get some data from a simple database that I have created using a separate control on the main form. This program runs however when I try to view the main form in designer view I get this exception "ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."

This is my code for the GetControl:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public partial class GetControl : UserControl
    {
        private SqlCeConnection mConnection = null;
        private SqlCeDataReader dataReader = null;

        public SqlCeConnection Connection
        {
            set { mConnection = value; }
        }

        public GetControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getData();
            addData();
        }

        private void getData()
        {
            SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts", mConnection);
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }

        private void addData()
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                contactList.Items.Add(dataReader.GetString(0) + " "
                    + dataReader.GetString(1));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my main form:

```
namespace Phonebook_Application
{
    public partial class Phonebook_MainForm : Form
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Phonebook.sdf;Persist Security Info=false;");

        public Phonebook_MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            con.Open();
            getControl1.Connection = con;
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to work fine if I call getData() and addData() in a button handler but not in form load. The project still runs without errors I just get that exception when trying to view designer view in the main form.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Visual Studio creates an instance of your form in the Designer, so any _Load type events and your default constructor will be executed.

You can check if you are in Design time by examining the [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c58hb4bw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property, although there are [limitations](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/04/11/1246.aspx) but your case DesignMode should suffice.

Example:

```
void MyMainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  //Do any UI Init Stuff (Icons etc.) here.

  if (!DesignMode)
  {
    //Business Logic (call databases etc.) here.
  }
}
```

Comment: ^_^ Hey thanks very much I added that to my GetControl_Load method and it works great now.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark this as an answer and up vote it if it was useful, that's how this site works so well : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ?